# How bypass ZTE factory reset protection

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset

I did a factory data reset on phone and it still wants the last synced Google account.

I found phone and would like to bypass factory reset protection, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, can't guarantee this will work but I've had success in the past using this method.
First complete factory reset with no Wi-Fi connection. Don't enter ANY information or password, knock, pattern, anything..
Next, turn off phone, then hold power and vol up till phone cycles on.
Again, ENTER NO INFORMATION. Now, power off and back on normally with no Wi-Fi.
Disable auto sync and connect your new Google account..
Voilà